# For if statement, although it is true, it loops again

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clearKeyboard(void){

    while(getchar()!='\n');
}

void pause(void){

    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...");
    clearKeyboard();
}


int getMenuChoice(void){

    int choice;
    printf("1- List all items\n");
    printf("2- Search by SKU\n");
    printf("0- Exit program\n> ");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    return choice;
}

int getYesOrNo(void){

    char ch;
    int ret;
    ch = 0;
    ret = 0;

    while(ch != 'Y' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'N' || ch != 'n')
    {
            scanf("%c", &ch);
            clearKeyboard();
            if (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y'){
                    ret = 1;
                    return ret;
            }
            if (ch == 'N' || ch == 'n'){
                    ret = 0;
                    return ret;
            }
            else if (ch != 'Y' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'N' || ch != 'n'){
                    printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable: ");
            }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(void){

    int choice;
    int temp = 0;
    choice = 0;

    printf("=== TEST MENU ===\n");
    pause();
    while(temp == 0){
            choice = getMenuChoice();
            if (choice != 0){
                    printf("*** not implemented ***\n");
            }
            else{
                    printf("Do you really want to quit? ");
                    temp = getYesOrNo();
            }
    }
    printf("=== END OF MENU TEST ===\n");

    return 0;

}
```

When the code runs, it should print out **the test menu**
and I would have to **press enter to continue**

Then, it would display **multiples of print statements**(listall..search by...exit)

So, if the user types 0 in, it asks Do you really want to quit and if the user types y, it should quit

However, the problem is the program asks the user unnecessary question "Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable" one more time after it asks "Do you really want to quit?" when I already have typed y in which is valid answer.

Why is that?

p.s library is there existing

Comment: please format the code properly. And choose one language. Looks like C to me, but if yuo compile it with a C++ compiler, then I would call it C++

Comment: `char ch;` -- ch is declared, but not initialized. Immediately afterwards, `ch` is compared to. This is undefined behavior, and a bug.

Comment: This `(ch != 'Y' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'N' || ch != 'n')` will never be false, no matter which value `ch` carries. So it can be replaced by `while(1)`.

Comment: unrelated to the question, but what made you think `clearKeyboard` is a good name for that method? I found that super confusing

Comment: You want to "clear the keyboard" after the call to `getMenuChoice` as well or even better just after `scanf("%d", &choice);`.

Comment: It worked as soon as i called the clearkeyboard after choice = getMenuChoice thank you everyone for valuable advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanf ("%d", &choice); consumes only the numeral character ( also crashes on any other input, iirc) but not the \r \l or \n characters, which will be consumed during the getYesOrNo function, if I am correct (somebody please correct me). That's why the program should display the (y)es/(n)o reminder directly after asking you whether you'd really want to quit.

That is also the reason why adding the clearKeyboard function makes it work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other issues with that code (e.g. the UB mentioned in a comment). However, this

```
        if (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y'){
                ret = 1;
                return ret;
        }
        if (ch == 'N' || ch == 'n'){
                ret = 0;
                return ret;
        }
        else if (ch != 'Y' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'N' || ch != 'n'){
                printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable: ");
        }
```

Is probably not what you want. The first `if` is independent of the `if - else` that comes afterwards, thus even if the first condition is true, the block after that will be evaluated. Most likely you want this instead:

```
        if (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y'){
                ret = 1;
                return ret;
        }
        else if (ch == 'N' || ch == 'n'){
                ret = 0;
                return ret;
        }
        else {
                printf("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable: ");
        }
```

The condition `ch != 'Y' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'N' || ch != 'n'` wasnt really meaningful, as the character is always either not Y or not N, thus it was always true.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a whitespace  before `%c` to automatically skip any leading whitespaces.In your case `'\n'` is always stored into ch which is why  `else if (ch != 'Y' || ch != 'y' || ch != 'N' || ch != 'n')` is always true

---

`scanf(" %c", &ch); //This is the modified statement`